# Random Forest implementation in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

all!

Could anybody give me an advice on Random Forest implementation in Python? Ideally I need something that outputs as much information about the classifiers as possible, especially:

1. which vectors from the train set are used to train each decision
   trees
2. which features are selected at random in each node in each
   tree, which samples from the training set end up in this node, which
   feature(s) are selected for split and which threashold is used for
   split

I have found quite some implementations, the most well known one is probably from scikit, but it is not clear how to do (1) and (2) there (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601134/decision-tree-classifier-how-do-i-get-calculation-of-the-value-parameter-of-und) question). Other implementations seem to have the same problems, except the one from openCV, but it is in C++ (python interface does not cover all methods for Random Forests).

Does anybody know something that satisfies (1) and (2)? Alternatively, any idea how to improve scikit implementation to get the features (1) and (2)?

**Solved:** checked the source code of sklearn.tree._tree.Tree. It has good comments (which fully describe the tree):

```
 children_left : int*
    children_left[i] holds the node id of the left child of node i.
    For leaves, children_left[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_left[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] <= threshold[i].

children_right : int*
    children_right[i] holds the node id of the right child of node i.
    For leaves, children_right[i] == TREE_LEAF. Otherwise,
    children_right[i] > i. This child handles the case where
    X[:, feature[i]] > threshold[i].

feature : int*
    feature[i] holds the feature to split on, for the internal node i.

threshold : double*
    threshold[i] holds the threshold for the internal node i.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get nearly all the information in scikit-learn. What exactly was the problem? You can even visualize the trees using dot.
I don't think you can find out which split candidates were sampled at random, but you can find out which were selected in the end.
Edit: Look at the `tree_` property of [the decision tree](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier). I agree, it is not very well documented. There really should be an example to visualize the leaf distributions etc. You can have a look at the visualization function to get an understanding of how to get to the properties.

Comment: Yes, i visualized the tree and also checked tree_ structure, hoping to get something out of there, but i could not get to the indices of training examples going at each subtree for example (there are just no indices that would correspond to training examples)

Comment: These indices are in the random forest afaik. Look at how the OOB score is computed.